# Python - Como calcular o antecessor de um número?

Tags: python

Elabore uma função chamada antecessor que receba como parâmetro único um número inteiro a  e que imprima o seu antecessor.

Entrada
A entrada consiste de uma única linha contendo o número inteiro da entrada a (10^-5<a<10^5).

Saída
Imprima em uma única linha o antecessor de a.

Eu fiz assim, mas não tá dando certo.

```
def antecessor(a):
    ant = a - 1
    print(ant)
    
a = int(input())
antecessor(a)
```

Comment: Eu executei o seu código, para mim funcionou. Qual a mensagem de erro que está recebendo?

Comment: Se enunciado é exatamente esse *...Elabore uma função chamada antecessor que receba como parâmetro único um número inteiro a e que imprima o seu antecessor....* não tem nada de errado com o seu código. Agora se o enunciado for algo levemente diferente, exemplo *...Elabore uma função chamada antecessor que receba como parâmetro único um número inteiro a e que retorne o seu antecessor....* ai então você tem um problema.

Answer (score 1):

Fica difícil entender sem o código de erro, porém vou tentar ajudar:

> Você poderia utilizar Loop **While** assim:

```
def read_input(num):
    while True:
        try:
            c = int(input(num))
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            print("\033[31mERRO! Por favor digite um numero inteiro...\033[m")
            continue
        except (KeyboardInterrupt):
            print("\033[31mEntrada de valor interrompida, por favor, reinicie o programa\033[31m")
            break
        else:
            return c


while True:
    numero = read_input('Digite um numero: ')
    antecessor = numero - 1
    print(f'O antecessor de seu numero é {antecessor}')
```

Neste exemplo eu também utilizei a função criada para tratar erros caso o usuário digite uma variavel diferente de int, `read_input()`. Mas ela não precisa ser utlizada, como neste exemplo:

```
while True:
    numero = int(input('Digite um numero: '))
    antecessor = numero - 1
    print(f'O antecessor de seu numero é {antecessor}')
```

Basicamente o loop while está sendo utilizado apenas para manter o programa rodando, mas ele não é necessário:

```
numero = int(input('Digite um numero: '))
antecessor = numero - 1
print(f'O antecessor de seu numero é {antecessor}')
```

> Utilizando a **criação de funções**

```
def calc_antecessor():
    numero = int(input('Digite um numero: '))
    antecessor = numero - 1
    print(f'O antecessor de seu numero é {antecessor}')


calc_antecessor()
```

Você também poderia utilizar aqui o loop while, o colocando antes de chamar a função

*Você poderia juntar tudo, como a criação de funções, loop while e tratamento de erro desta forma:*

```
def read_input(num):
    while True:
        try:
            c = int(input(num))
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            print("\033[31mERRO! Por favor digite um numero inteiro...\033[m")
            continue
        except (KeyboardInterrupt):
            print("\033[31mEntrada de valor interrompida, por favor, reinicie o programa\033[31m")
            break
        else:
            return c

def calc_antecessor():
    numero = read_input('Digite um numero: ')
    antecessor = numero - 1
    print(f'O antecessor de seu numero é {antecessor}')

while True:
    calc_antecessor()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = int(input('Digite um número: '))
b = a - 1
print('O antecessor de ', a, ' é ', b)
```

Seria isso?